# R - calculate proportions across columns with common prefix

Tags: r, dplyr, group, startswith

I have a dataframe with 37 columns in it, with a representative sample, `df` below

```
 df <- structure(list(irm = 201201:201202, trans11 = c(379L, 433L), 
    trans12 = 4:3, trans13 = 5:4, trans14 = c(13L, 3L), trans15 = c(29L, 
    21L), trans16 = c(0L, 0L), trans21 = c(6L, 4L), trans22 = 2:1, 
    trans23 = c(0L, 0L), trans24 = 0:1, trans25 = c(0L, 0L), 
    trans26 = c(0L, 0L), trans31 = c(2L, 2L), trans32 = c(0L, 
    0L), trans33 = 5:6, trans34 = c(0L, 0L), trans35 = c(7L, 
    2L), trans36 = c(0L, 0L), trans41 = c(4L, 10L), trans42 = c(0L, 
    0L), trans43 = c(0L, 0L), trans44 = c(4L, 10L), trans45 = c(3L, 
    1L), trans46 = c(0L, 0L), trans51 = c(15L, 18L), trans52 = c(0L, 
    0L), trans53 = c(1L, 1L), trans54 = c(4L, 0L), trans55 = c(96L, 
    115L), trans56 = c(0L, 0L), trans61 = c(0L, 0L), trans62 = c(0L, 
    0L), trans63 = c(0L, 0L), trans64 = c(0L, 0L), trans65 = c(0L, 
    0L), trans66 = c(0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

The dataframe has 37 columns:  `trans11`...`trans16`...`trans61`...`trans66` plus the `irm` column for month.

What I would like to do is the following:

1. for each row/column entry in `trans11` all the way through `trans66`, calculate the proportion of the entry relative to the sum of all other columns with the same prefix (e.g. `trans1`).  So for the example here, the first row  in entries 2 through 7 would be:  `(0.8813953, 0.009302326, 0.01162791, 0.03023256, 0.06744186, 0)` for columns 2 through 7 (since we need to sum `trans11`....`trans16`)
2. How would I do this for all 36 columns in the larger df?

Is there a way to do this with `group_by` and `starts_with` from `dplyr`?  I know a `for` loop is probably possible but any and all suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

***Updated example with larger dataframe example***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in base R use `prop.table/propotions`:

```
cbind(df, prop = prop.table(as.matrix(df[-1]), 1))

      irm trans11 trans12 trans13 trans14 trans15 trans16 prop.trans11 prop.trans12 prop.trans13 prop.trans14 prop.trans15 prop.trans16
1  201201     379       4       5      13      29       0    0.8813953  0.009302326  0.011627907  0.030232558   0.06744186            0
2  201202     433       3       4       3      21       0    0.9331897  0.006465517  0.008620690  0.006465517   0.04525862            0
3  201203     468       2       9       9      19       0    0.9230769  0.003944773  0.017751479  0.017751479   0.03747535            0
4  201204     514       3       9       8      15       0    0.9362477  0.005464481  0.016393443  0.014571949   0.02732240            0
5  201205     559      11       8       6      12       0    0.9379195  0.018456376  0.013422819  0.010067114   0.02013423            0
6  201206     566       5       9       6      16       0    0.9401993  0.008305648  0.014950166  0.009966777   0.02657807            0
7  201207     577       3      13       4      21       0    0.9336570  0.004854369  0.021035599  0.006472492   0.03398058            0
8  201208     622       7      14      10      15       0    0.9311377  0.010479042  0.020958084  0.014970060   0.02245509            0
9  201209     665       4      12       3      11       0    0.9568345  0.005755396  0.017266187  0.004316547   0.01582734            0
10 201210     692       4      11       7      15       0    0.9492455  0.005486968  0.015089163  0.009602195   0.02057613            0
11 201211     738       6       5       5       9       0    0.9672346  0.007863696  0.006553080  0.006553080   0.01179554            0
12 201212     830       8       8       4      11       0    0.9639954  0.009291521  0.009291521  0.004645761   0.01277584            0
```

---

If you need to select using `trans` name:

```
cbind(df, prop = prop.table(as.matrix(df[startsWith(names(df), 'trans')]), 1))
```

---

### Edit

With the edit of the data, use:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with('trans'), names_to = c('tr', 'grp'), 
                 names_pattern = '(.*)(.)') %>%
  mutate(value = value/sum(value), .by = c(irm, tr)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(tr, grp), names_sep = '', names_prefix = 'prop_')
```

Comment: thanks, i updated the data so that it's easier to understand.  i should have given a wider array from the beginning

Answer (score 3):

```
df |>
  mutate(
    row_sum = rowSums(across(starts_with("trans"))),
    across(starts_with("trans"), \(x) x / row_sum, .names = "{.col}_prop")
    )
#        irm trans11 trans12 trans13 trans14 trans15 trans16 row_sum trans11_prop trans12_prop
#  1: 201201     379       4       5      13      29       0     430    0.8813953  0.009302326
#  2: 201202     433       3       4       3      21       0     464    0.9331897  0.006465517
#  3: 201203     468       2       9       9      19       0     507    0.9230769  0.003944773
#  4: 201204     514       3       9       8      15       0     549    0.9362477  0.005464481
#  5: 201205     559      11       8       6      12       0     596    0.9379195  0.018456376
#  6: 201206     566       5       9       6      16       0     602    0.9401993  0.008305648
#  7: 201207     577       3      13       4      21       0     618    0.9336570  0.004854369
#  8: 201208     622       7      14      10      15       0     668    0.9311377  0.010479042
#  9: 201209     665       4      12       3      11       0     695    0.9568345  0.005755396
# 10: 201210     692       4      11       7      15       0     729    0.9492455  0.005486968
# 11: 201211     738       6       5       5       9       0     763    0.9672346  0.007863696
# 12: 201212     830       8       8       4      11       0     861    0.9639954  0.009291521
#     trans13_prop trans14_prop trans15_prop trans16_prop
#  1:  0.011627907  0.030232558   0.06744186            0
#  2:  0.008620690  0.006465517   0.04525862            0
#  3:  0.017751479  0.017751479   0.03747535            0
#  4:  0.016393443  0.014571949   0.02732240            0
#  5:  0.013422819  0.010067114   0.02013423            0
#  6:  0.014950166  0.009966777   0.02657807            0
#  7:  0.021035599  0.006472492   0.03398058            0
#  8:  0.020958084  0.014970060   0.02245509            0
#  9:  0.017266187  0.004316547   0.01582734            0
# 10:  0.015089163  0.009602195   0.02057613            0
# 11:  0.006553080  0.006553080   0.01179554            0
# 12:  0.009291521  0.004645761   0.01277584            0
```

You can, of course, drop the `row_sum` column after.

Comment: thanks.  i went ahead and updated the data in the example to make it easier to understand

Comment: I don't see how a larger data frame changes anything. Is this result correct? If not, please explain how. If you look in the first row, the `_prop` columns have values `(0.8813953, 0.009302326, 0.01162791, 0.03023256, 0.06744186, 0)`, just as described in your question.

Comment: when i run the code on the updated example, it gives `c(0.6545769, 0.006908463,
0.008635579, 0.022452504, 0.05008636)`  instead of the values you have, which are correct, for `trans11_prop`...`trans16_prop`.

Comment: Oh, so you have multiple column groups, and they need to be grouped by the first digit?

Comment: If that's the case, then I think TarJae's answer with the pivot will be easiest, you will just need one extra step to parse out the first digit for grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plain tidyverse solution by first pivoting into long format, doing the calculation and then pivoting to wide.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-irm, names_to = "trans", values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(sum_group = sum(value), proportion = value / sum_group, .by=c(irm), .keep = "unused") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "trans", values_from = "proportion", names_glue = "{trans}_prop") %>% 
  right_join(df, join_by(irm))
```

```
 irm sum_group trans11_prop trans12_prop trans13_prop trans14_prop trans15_prop trans16_prop trans11 trans12 trans13 trans14 trans15 trans16
    <int>     <int>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
 1 201201       430        0.881      0.00930      0.0116       0.0302        0.0674            0     379       4       5      13      29       0
 2 201202       464        0.933      0.00647      0.00862      0.00647       0.0453            0     433       3       4       3      21       0
 3 201203       507        0.923      0.00394      0.0178       0.0178        0.0375            0     468       2       9       9      19       0
 4 201204       549        0.936      0.00546      0.0164       0.0146        0.0273            0     514       3       9       8      15       0
 5 201205       596        0.938      0.0185       0.0134       0.0101        0.0201            0     559      11       8       6      12       0
 6 201206       602        0.940      0.00831      0.0150       0.00997       0.0266            0     566       5       9       6      16       0
 7 201207       618        0.934      0.00485      0.0210       0.00647       0.0340            0     577       3      13       4      21       0
 8 201208       668        0.931      0.0105       0.0210       0.0150        0.0225            0     622       7      14      10      15       0
 9 201209       695        0.957      0.00576      0.0173       0.00432       0.0158            0     665       4      12       3      11       0
10 201210       729        0.949      0.00549      0.0151       0.00960       0.0206            0     692       4      11       7      15       0
11 201211       763        0.967      0.00786      0.00655      0.00655       0.0118            0     738       6       5       5       9       0
12 201212       861        0.964      0.00929      0.00929      0.00465       0.0128            0     830       8       8       4      11       0
```